# Problemas con un ArrayCollection de doctrine Symfony

Tags: php, doctrine, collection, ddd

tengo una duda para un proyecto demo que estoy realizando. Le dejo el repo para que puedan ver el proyecto completo [Repo Github](https://github.com/frannixo95/ddd-first-proyect)

Estoy empezando a usar DDD y arquitectura hexagonal en un proyecto, pero me he topado con un pequeño muro que no tengo muy claro como resolverlo.

Tengo un caso de uso que es el de crear un **Video** Tengo una clase video que tiene unas propiedades base, hasta este punto todo bien, la creación de este recurso en pase de datos no hay problema con una relación one-to-many añadiendo una segunda clase subtitle donde le indico en que idioma están los subtitle.

El problema lo tengo a la hora de realizar un **Get /videos** de esos video, que necesito traer los subtitle asociados a los videos ya que la clase Video se le requiere por constructor un **SubtitleCollection**.

Pero no se como hacer una búsqueda de esos subtitle ya que el campo **video_id** que genera doctrine para la relacción no es accesible por un findBy.

El problema lo tengo en la siguiente ruta **VideoLibrary/Api/Infrastructure/Persistence/Doctrine/Repository/DoctrineVideoRepository.php** en el metodo **toDomain** que debo de pasarle como último parámetro un **SubtitleCollection** (ArrayCollection de doctrine)

Espero que puedan entender a lo que me refiero, he intentado explicarlo de la forma más simple posible.

Un saludo y gracias por la ayuda!! :)

Comment: Puedes copiar aquí el código que te da problemas? Twn en cuenta que, al ser un repo, cuando lo corrijas o si lo pones privado, luego la gente no puede ver el problema y no será muy útil la respuesta para otra gente que busque algo parecido

Comment: El código lo tienes en el repo, sería mucho código para ponerlo en el post, como ya indico la ruta VideoLibrary/Api/Infrastructure/Persistence/Doctrine/Repository/DoctrineVideoRepository.php en el metodo toDomain